# How to transfer files between Galaxy S3 and HTC one x using NFC

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, htc-one-x, nfc

As I have mentioned in the question, I want to transfer files (pics) from samsung galaxy S3 to HTC one x via NFC. I have switched on android beam on both the devices. When I bring the phones close, I am getting the "touch to beam" message on S3. When I touch it, I am getting a message that S beam is switched off, please switch it on. But I dont want Sbeam (as one x doesnt have it), instead I want the transfer to happen via Android beam.

Comment: Have you tried installing another NFC transfer app?  Also, have you tried just using Sbeam?

Comment: @MBraedley No /i havent tried other apps because I didnt want to install the apps on both the phones. Also Sbeam between two S3s is working fine, but since one x doesnt support Sbeam, I didnt try that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't transfer files over Android beam, just URLs/locations etc. This is because Android Beam doesn't use Bluetooth or WiFi Direct in addition to the NFC transfer, which means that an average photo would take 30+ seconds to beam. In Android 4.1+ (Jelly Bean) you can transfer files with NFC+BT, and S Beam uses NFC+WiFi Direct.

Comment: so NFC + BT is not there in ICS ?

Comment: No, it was a new feature added in JB ([source](http://www.engadget.com/2012/06/27/google-details-jelly-bean-nfc-features-android-beam-upgrade-ta/)).

Comment: [anonymous comment] *All you have to do is turn s beam off and leave NFC on. I just did it with picture and video from gs3 to my HTC onex*

Answer (score 0):

You can install the official 'HTC transfer Tool' from the Google Play store on your old S3 and new HTC One.  Pure simplicity :)

Comment: Please also add a play store link to the tool.